# Search a file (10MB+) for keywords occuring in a similar context (<512 word length away)

Tags: python, string, algorithm, nlp

I want to extract paragraphs from a file where input keywords occur together or a certain distance apart (maximum `~512` words apart). The file size is `10MB` and although it would've been fine to do a naive search for every keyword, I am passing each of the paragraphs (in which the words occur) to a model which takes around ~1-2s to get results. There can also be more than `1000` occurrences of certain keywords. This makes it extremely slow.

What I have tried playing with is Longest Common Subsequence and Minkowski distance but they don't really fit here as in the former case ordering of keywords is important and the latter doesn't make sense to me in this particular case.

One thing I can possibly do is to remove unimportant words (such as stopwords) and then run this process again, but I doubt if it will still be better.
I will also need to use top `k` paragraphs, which I will keep around `10`.

The text file are novels/books.

As an example, in Harry Potter book I want paragraphs where the keywords "Uncle Vernon", "Hogwarts", "Harry", "Letter" occur together.

How can I do it more efficiently?

Comment: why don't u use Lucene to index and retrieve the paragraphs?

Comment: in a single iteration make a list of word index for every key word, now you have a group of sorted lists, you want to find groups that appear in all lists in a boundary of 512 words, again a single iteration

Comment: @trigonom I think it could work here. What else do you suggest about getting the top few results following this method, something like absolute distance between each pair of words?

Comment: @Debasis can you recommend something for Python? I looked into pylucene but couldn't find good documentation or where to get started.

Comment: i would advise to use the Java version as a blackbox retriever... use my mavenized version (https://github.com/gdebasis/luc4ir) for which u don't need to write a single line of code... u just need to format ur documents as a 2 column file (id \t content) - which u can do in Python... for viewing the content there's a script in the repository called viewdocs.sh

Answer (score 0):

[image]

suppose this is the table you have
you begin with every one first index and check the distance between lowest and highest,
in this case 77-5 = 72

you move to the next index with the lowest and check again

every time you move forward with the lowest index and check if the dif between lowest and highest is lower then distance you deiced

it might miss some cases

after a successful group you need to check all of the words next option
[image]

consider the above, after first group you will move forward with Harry and miss 2 groups of Hogwarts next index and of uncle vernon next index